# How can I handle this variation?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11

Find Maximum sum in an array such that no 2 elements are adjacent. In this, 1 more condition was also there that first and last elements should also not be taken together.

If it would have been without the last condition, that is, then I developed the following code wherein I take two variables, `incl` and `excl` and find out the values. It is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int i,n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[100];
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        cin>>arr[i];
    int incl,excl,excls;
    incl = arr[0];
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if (incl > excl)
            excls = incl;
        else
            excls = excl;
        incl = excl + arr[i];
        excl = excls;
    }
    if (incl > excl)
        cout<<incl;
    else
        cout<<excl;
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How can I modify this for that special case? Thanks!

Comment: How do distinguish consecutive elements?

Answer (score 0):

To account for the special case, you could run your existing algorithm twice.

The first time you compute the best sum over the first n-1 elements in the array.  This will calculate the best sum that definitely does not include the last element.

The second time you compute the best sum over the last n-1 elements in the array.  This will calculate the best sum that definitely does not include the first element.

The best answer will be the best of these two results.

(by the way, you are not initializing the variable excl so you may get incorrect results sometimes)